# Idea: Create Wikis for popular app categories

Tags: feature-request, apps, wiki

Hey guys,

I just thought of a pretty good idea in my opinion after reading a question like [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2840/comparision-of-video-players-for-android) for the 10th time.

What if we start small Wiki posts for certain popular categories like:

- Music Players
- Video Players
- Home Screen Launchers
- SMS apps
- more...

We could list apps that are the most popular on the market these days and have small sentences describing the app and what makes it unique/popular. This would be a good reference for people interested in same Music Players to go and find the popular ones out there and what their differences are.

What do you guys think?

NB. We could make certain conditions for app to be listed like... they must have over say 5,000 downloads and a minimum rating of 3 stars just to cut out the junk apps.

Comment: I'm not against lists, as long as they are high-quality and properly maintained

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something that would be quite useful. If it were one App per Answer, then each app could be individually voted up/down as well as comments left against it...so each answer in itself is useful...